# JQuery Selector issue (I think)

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I've got the script below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ChildMenusFound = $(".menu_Child").hover(function () {
            //Mouse Over
                            alert('ok');
            $(this).toggleClass("menu_hover");
        }, function () {
            //Mouse Out
                            alert('ok');
            $(this).toggleClass("menu_hover");
        });
    });
</Script>
```

The html I'm outputting is as follows:

```
<ul alt="" class="menu_Root">
<li class="menu_Child>"
<a href="/Admin" alt="">Admin</a>
<ul alt="" class="menu_Child">
<li class="menu_SubMenu>"
<a href="/Admin/Statistics" alt="">Statistics</a></li>
<li class="menu_SubMenu>"
<a href="/Admin/Database" alt="">Database</a></li>
</ul></li>

<li class="menu_Child>"
<a href="/MyAccount" alt="">My Account</a>
<ul alt="" class="menu_Child">
<li class="menu_SubMenu>"
<a href="/MyAccount/Profile" alt="">Profile</a></li>
</ul></li>

</ul>
```

after the call to hover(),`ChildMenusFound` contains 2 elements, firefox shows no JS errors, yet mouseover/out of the li elements doesn't cause anything to happen.

Can someone please identify my mistake?

Comment: What is var ChildMenusFound for?

Comment: debugging purpose only - I was alerting ChildMenusFound.length after the call to hover() so I could see how many elements the selector found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your markup is broken. You've got quote marks outside the tags. It also looks like you're missing a `</li>` somewhere for that first outer `</li>` but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Damn - thanks. I spent so long staring at the JQuery, I got tunnel vision.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is a bit off, you have classes unclosed (or wrongly closed) like this:

```
<li class="menu_Child>"
                      ^ here
```

It should be:

```
<li class="menu_Child">
```

[Here's the fixed/working version](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/GBUdt/), you can slim your code down though, like this:

```
$(function () {
  $(".menu_Child").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("menu_hover");
  });
});
```

With a single callback passed to [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) it's called in both in/out directions, and since you're toggling you can save code here.

Comment: I actually fixed that ug and undid it without noticing (CTRL-Z). Thanks for spotting it

Answer (score 1):

Other answers noted your broken HTML markup.

One thing to consider may be to use CSS instead of javascript to do your `hover`. It won't work in IE6 unless it is on an `<a>` element, but it will in most other browsers.

```
.menu_Child {
   background: yellow;
}

.menu_Child:hover {
   background: orange;
}
```

Not sure what the effect is you're going for, but if you can change the hovered element to the `<a>`, it will work in IE6 as well.

Comment: A good idea and one I'd usually apply by choice - In this instance, however, this is the start of a menu system and as well as toggling the class, I'm going to slide/hide sub-menus. Since I'm failing back to a CSS-only menu if JS isn't present, I'll use the hover approach there. The JQuery menu requires JS anyway so it's a convenience with no real cost.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, you have inverted two characters :

```
<li class="menu_Child>"
```

needs to became

```
<li class="menu_Child">
```